# How to fix fatal error: zlib.h: no such file or directory?

Tags: compilation, header-files, zlib

I'm trying to compile miniSAT on Kali Linux 64 bits but I keep getting the error message:

> fatal error: zlib.h: no such file or directory

I have read that there might be a linking problem that makes the compiler unable to find the header files, but I'm new to Linux and do not know how to solve that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation error - missing zlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148075/compilation-error-missing-zlib-h)

Answer (score 162):

You should install the development support files for zlib, try:

```
sudo apt-get install libz-dev
```

<sup>Other package names: `zlib1g-dev`.</sup>

If you've already `zlib` library, make sure you're compiling your code sources with `-lz`. See: [missing zlib.h in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22337896/55075).

Comment: Worked in Debian 10 and a Docker container built on Debian 10 for R 3.6.2 and RStudio

Comment: In CentOS, Fedora: `yum install zlib-devel`

Comment: It was still giving me errors even after I had the headers in /usr/include. I didn't know how to tell pip build system where to find standard header locations, so I created simlinks from the missing headers to the same folder as the other headers in the error message. Works

Answer (score 9):

Install zlib from it's source, solve my similar error.
Download last version from [this](https://zlib.net/) then:

```
configure
make -j4
make install
```