# Installing shiny on AWS EC2 ubuntu 20.4 fail

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny, ubuntu-20.04

I keep struggling installing shiny on a ubuntu 20.4 vm on EC2.
I followed [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04/) procedure.
Then I tried:

```
install.packages("shiny") 
install.packages("shiny", dependencies = T)
install.packages("shiny", dependencies = T, INSTALL_opts ='--no-lock')
```

I also add 4GB of SWAP memory.

But no way...

Here are my outputs:

> ** R
> ** demo
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error: package ‘promises’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
> Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘httpuv’
>
> - removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/httpuv’ ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
> - removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/httr’ ERROR: dependency ‘textshaping’ is not available for package ‘ragg’
> - removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ragg’ ERROR: dependency ‘httpuv’ is not available for package ‘shiny’
> - removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny’ ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘webdriver’
> - removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/webdriver’ ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘shiny’, ‘webdriver’, ‘httpuv’ are not available
>   for package ‘shinytest’
> - removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shinytest’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/tmp/RtmpGvP9AB/downloaded_packages’ Warning messages: 1: In
> install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE) :   installation of
> package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status 2: In
> install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE) :   installation of
> package ‘textshaping’ had non-zero exit status 3: In
> install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE) :   installation of
> package ‘httpuv’ had non-zero exit status 4: In
> install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE) :   installation of
> package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status 5: In
> install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE) :   installation of
> package ‘ragg’ had non-zero exit status 6: In
> install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE) :   installation of
> package ‘shiny’ had non-zero exit status 7: In
> install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE) :   installation of
> package ‘webdriver’ had non-zero exit status 8: In
> install.packages("shiny", dependencies = TRUE) :   installation of
> package ‘shinytest’ had non-zero exit status

Each time I try to install a dependency "by hand", an other missing one, deeper nested, shows up.

Could someone help me with this, please ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you described how you solved the problem as mentioned under one of the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install openssl R package, you'll also need system-wide installation of the samename package. You could try something like `sudo apt-get install openssl`. Search the internet for dependencies of other packages.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were able to solve your issues. Recently I also faced similar issues in trying to install Shiny server and related packages in EC2.  I researched a bit and came across a Rstudio server AMI (Amazon Machine Image)- https://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/, maintained by Louis Aslett. You can choose the AMI from the nearest region and once the instance is up and running, you can directly start using R-studio or Shiny. I find it very helpful.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, after manually installing missing packages, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://superuser.com/a/192687) answer on a thread talking about a different error in the same log, I was able to solve this issue for myself. Simply running `sudo apt-get install build-essential` fixed it for me. (I also then needed to run `sudo apt-get install libz-dev` after as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38277210/21810621) answer.)